# How to use Webcam video in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, webcam

I want to use webcam video in my XNA project. I searched it on net but I was unable to find anything useful. Is there any ready made project/class/tutorial that i can use?
Kindly guide me how to use webcam video in a XNA project easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the XNA Community Codeplex page, there are a few examples of XNA and WebCam usage:

[OpenCV and XNA](http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCV&XNA&referringTitle=Ejemplos)

[Motion Detection (part 1)](http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Detecci%C3%B3n%20movimientos&referringTitle=Ejemplos)

[Motion Detection (part 2)](http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Detecci%C3%B3n%20movimientos%20II&referringTitle=Ejemplos)